# How do I iterate over two ranges whilst keeping one the same?

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I want to iterate for this function that takes parameters theta, X and i.

`hypothesis = theta[0]*X[i][0] + theta[1]*X[i][1] + theta[2]*X[i][2] + ...`

theta is 1-D array and X is a 2-D array. I tried using for loops like this, but Im not sure how to run through all i for `theta[0]*X[i][0]` first then run through i for `theta[1]*X[i][1]` and so on.

```
for i in range(i):
    for j in range(j):
        hypothesis += theta[i]*X[j][i]
```

Comment: Please, use consistent variable names. First it's `X[i]`, then `X[j]`, and `for i in range(i)` is super confusing.

Comment: Does the order of addition make a difference? I ask because first you write `theta[0]*X[i][0] + theta[1]*X[i][1] + ...`, but then you imply `theta[0]*X[i][0] + theta[0]*X[i+1][0] + ...`

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do the dot product of theta with the ith row of X?

If so, then you could do something like this:

```py
def dot_product(theta, x, i):
  hypothesis = 0
  for j in range(len(theta)):
    hypothesis += theta[j] * x[i][j]
  return hypothesis
```

or you could make it more concise through Python's generator functionality:

```py
def dot_product(theta, x, i):
  return sum(theta[j] * x[i][j] for j in range(len(theta)))
```

Comment: `sum(map(operator.mul, theta, x[i]))`, or slightly more explicitly, `sum(t*xi for t, xi in zip(theta, x[i]))`.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed